# Trying to populate listview from sqlite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

I'm trying to populate a list view with data from my database:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_visualizar);
        EventoSQLHelper e = new EventoSQLHelper(this);
        e.Open();
        Cursor c = e.getRegistros();
        String resp = "";

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        ListView eventos = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_eventos);
        TextView tx = new TextView(this);
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
            resp = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("id"))
                    + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("descricao"))
                    + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("dataEvento"));
            list.add(resp);
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.activity_list_item,list);
        eventos.setAdapter(adpt);
        e.close();
    }
```

But it gave me an error:

```
09-20 14:35:19.300: E/AndroidRuntime(29881): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-20 14:35:19.300: E/AndroidRuntime(29881): Process: com.example.pacixmobile, PID: 29881
09-20 14:35:19.300: E/AndroidRuntime(29881): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
09-20 14:35:19.300: E/AndroidRuntime(29881):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
09-20 14:35:19.300: E/AndroidRuntime(29881):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
09-20 14:35:19.300: E/AndroidRuntime(29881):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2715)
09-20 14:35:19.300: E/AndroidRuntime(29881):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1274)
09-20 14:35:19.300: E/AndroidRuntime(29881):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1186)
09-20 14:35:19.300: E/AndroidRuntime(29881):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17387)
09-20 14:35:19.300: E/AndroidRuntime(29881):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:689)
```

I want to list the data and later i want to click on any item, and send a sms to a list of contacts. But i can't even list the data...what am i doing wrong?

Comment: what is the purpose of TextView tx = new TextView(this); ? I Remember using like this TextView tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewID);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
```

ArrayAdapter expects a resource that is just a TextView. `android.R.layout.activity_list_item` is a LinearLayout holding an ImageView and a TextView. Use `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` instead.